# How to update a value after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to set `isLogged` to 1 after login, login work but query doesn't work.

Query :

```
// 
public static string loginUpdate = @"UPDATE users SET isLogged = @isLogged WHERE username = @username";

//
public bool userLogin(string userName, string password)
{
        SqlConnection conn = db.initializare();
        UserModel user = null;
        int userId ; 
        int isLogged = 1;

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.loginCheck, conn);
            //cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.loginUpdate, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", userName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLogged", isLogged);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                userName = reader["username"].ToString();
                password = reader["password"].ToString();
                userId = Int32.Parse(reader["userID"].ToString());
                user = new UserModel(userName, password,userId);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.loginUpdate, conn);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var mesajEroare = ex.Message + "-" + ex.InnerException; ;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can you tell someone is logged *out*? What happens if someone logs-in and then immediately closes their browser-window and never clicks the logout button?

Comment: @marc_s if i add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); after cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.loginUpdate, conn); , when i try to login the webpage return false

Comment: @Dai, for log out, i will set isLogged = 0 in LogOut function, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Right after `cmd = new SqlCommand(Query.loginUpdate, conn);`, add `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` - otherwise, that query is **never executed**! The return value from this call is an `INT` tellling you how many rows were affected by your operation - **1** if you found a user to update, **0** if not....

Comment: @marc_s, As a result of your suggestions I found out that the query is not running, is there a problem with it? (writing?) ( int i; i=cmd,ExecuteNonQuery(); remain 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to write two separate `SqlCommands` to perform two operations:

1. For login check
2. For login update

Also, always make it a habit to use the `using statement` when dealing with an object that eats resources such as `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. so objects will be automatically disposed after using them.

This will make your code cleaner without explicitly calling the `Dispose()` call.

Finally, I would suggest you place your SQL operation outside your `Button Click` event to avoid getting your code more complex. That way it's clean and easy to manage.

To summarize that, here's how your code is going to look like:

```
private string GetUserPassword(string userName){
    using (SqlConnection connection = db.initializare()) {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = @UserName";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)) {
             connection.Open();
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

             var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
             return (result == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : result;
        }
    }
}


private void UpdateLogin(string userName, int isLogged){
    using (SqlConnection connection = db.initializare()) {
        string sqlQuery = "UPDATE users SET isLogged = @isLogged WHERE username = @username";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)) {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isLogged", isLogged);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

public bool UserLogin(string userName, string password)
{
    string userPassword = GetUserPassword(userName);
    if (password.Equals(userPassword)){
        UpdateLogin(userName,1);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //username or password is incorrect
    }  

    return false;
}
```